# Error connecting to update server 18.01.04.LTS

Tags: networking, updates, dns

I cannot connect to any ubuntu servers (tried several) even though the http/https protocol runs fine on the machine.

I get the same error when I try to update using the software updater.

I checked if it might be a name server problem but apparently not. 
I do not get any response when ı ping google DNS's (4.4.4.4, 4.4.4.8)

I would be grateful to hear any suggestions..  :_(

---

```
> swashbuckler@swashbuckler-All-Series:/etc$ sudo apt-get update Err:1
> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
> Could not connect to 192.168.1.253:80 (192.168.1.253). - connect (113:
> No route to host) Err:2 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu
> bionic-cran35/ InRelease   Unable to connect to 192.168.1.253:http:
> Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease  
> Unable to connect to 192.168.1.253:http: Err:4
> http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rrutter/ubuntu bionic InRelease  
> Unable to connect to 192.168.1.253:http: Err:5
> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease   Unable
> to connect to 192.168.1.253:http: Err:6
> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease   Unable to
> connect to 192.168.1.253:http: Reading package lists... Done W: Failed
> to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease 
> Could not connect to 192.168.1.253:80 (192.168.1.253). - connect (113:
> No route to host) W: Failed to fetch
> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease 
> Unable to connect to 192.168.1.253:http: W: Failed to fetch
> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease 
> Unable to connect to 192.168.1.253:http: W: Failed to fetch
> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease 
> Unable to connect to 192.168.1.253:http: W: Failed to fetch
> http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/bionic-cran35/InRelease 
> Unable to connect to 192.168.1.253:http: W: Failed to fetch
> http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rrutter/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease
> Unable to connect to 192.168.1.253:http: W: Some index files failed to
> download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: google dns is 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 if i remember well

Comment: You have network (most likely routing) issues.  192.168.x.x is a local address and cannot route externally; so I'd check you have a routing that makes sense, check for unusual things in your HOSTS file, and check your DNS (looking for something that points real addresses like ubuntu.com to 192.168 (or internal addresses).  You may need to setup a proxy...

Comment: Apparently I have no advancement on the issue so far. :-(  My HOSTS file is all empty, I have no proxy what-so-ever and still get the same response..Err:5 
  Unable to connect to 192.168.1.253:http:
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to 192.168.1.253:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to 192.168.1.253:80 (192.168.1.253). - connect (113: No route to host)
....
All suggestions are still welcome :_(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I fixed it in this way:

1. I deleted the file /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init^_copy.yaml. It was, as if by magic, in the netplan folder. It will also have been the "troublemaker". This was always listed in the error message mentioned.
2. Then I tested `sudo netplan --debug apply` and got a System-Debug-Configuration für the correct network settings.

Here is myn:

`network:
  bonds: {}
  bridges: {}
  ethernets:
    enp3s0f0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.178.122/24
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: true
      gateway4: 192.168.178.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.178.33
        - 192.168.178.1
      optional: true
    enp3s0f1:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.178.123/24
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: true
      gateway4: 192.168.178.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.178.33
        - 192.168.178.1
      optional: true
    enp4s0f0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.178.124/24
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: true
      gateway4: 192.168.178.33
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.178.33
        - 192.168.178.1
      optional: true
    enp4s0f1:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.178.125/24
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: true
      gateway4: 192.168.178.33
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.178.33
        - 192.168.178.1
      optional: true
  vlans: {}
  wifis: {}`

3. This configuration I dropped into the original 50-cloud-init-yaml, and saved to it.
4. With `sudo netplan apply` I restarted netplan. `sudo ifconfig` showed me the correct configuration and I get internet connection to apt and so on.